# Problems making batch request in SPFx

Tags: sharepoint, sharepointframework

Cheers guys and gals.

Having some problems with $batching requests to SP from SPFx.

Some background: The SP structure has one site collection with lots of subsites. Each subsite has a list whose name is identical on all subsites. I need to access all of those lists.

A normal SPHttpClient call gives me the url of all of the sites. So far so good.

The plan was then to $batch the calls to get the data from the lists. Unfortunatly I only get the answer from one of the calls. The rest of the batched calls gives me "InvalidClientQueryException". If I change the order of the calls it seems like only the first call succeeds.

```
const spBatchCreationOptions: ISPHttpClientBatchCreationOptions = {
     webUrl: absoluteUrl
};

const spBatch: SPHttpClientBatch = spHttpClient.beginBatch(spBatchCreationOptions);

// Add three calls to the batch
const dan1 = spBatch.get("<endpoint1>",SPHttpClientBatch.configurations.v1);
const dan2 = spBatch.get("<endpoint2>",SPHttpClientBatch.configurations.v1);
const dan3 = spBatch.get("<endpoint3>",SPHttpClientBatch.configurations.v1);

// Execute the batch
       spBatch.execute().then(() => {

            dan1.then((res1) => {
                return res1.json().then((res10) => {
                    console.log(res10);
                });
            });

            dan2.then((res2) => {
                return res2.json().then((res20) => {
                    console.log(res20);
                });
            });

            dan3.then((res3) => {
                return res3.json().then((res30) => {
                    console.log(res30);
                });
            });
 });
```

So in this case only the call dan1 succeeds. If I however change call2 to have an identical endpoint as the first call they both succeed.

I can't really wrap my head around this, so if someone has any input it would be much appreciated.
//Dan

Comment: what is the endpoint that you are calling ? So far the code looks correct, maybe the issue is related to the endpoint. Can you provide more details ? Also, what if you "hard-code" the endpoint for testing purpose ? Does it work then ?

Comment: The endpoint is <url>/projekt/NyaVagar/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Projektinformation')/items where NyaVagar is one of the subsites. At the moment though it is hard-coded. No dynamic funcionality is implemented yet. I'm sure all three endpoints are correct because if I swap the order of them the one at is added first works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your endpoint is always the same site per one batch. You cannot mix different sites within one batch. In that case only the first call(s) will succeed which are from the same site.
To overcome that you might switch to a search call in case you wanna retrieve information (what you can do over the same site URL).
See my [blogpost](https://mmsharepoint.wordpress.com/2018/06/08/use-sharepoint-rest-api-batch-component-to-retrieve-site-logos/) on that for further information.